# Using ColumnTransformer to add a feature to vectorizer content, getting dimensions error when trying to fit content

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.7

I'm having an issue adding a feature to vectorizer content. I have the text content and the number of pages and I am adding the pages to the vectorizer input using the ColumnTransformer sklearn function like this

```
training_content = pd.DataFrame({'text': training_text,'pages': training_pages})
```

The dimensions of the text content and the pages are the same

```
19872 19872
```

The resulting DataFrame has this shape

```
(19872, 2)
```

Then I am using the ColumnTransformer to generate a pipeline for the feature preprocessing

```
pipe = ColumnTransformer([('text', TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=remove_strings_smaller_three_chars_tokenizer,  ngram_range=(1,ngram)), ['text'])], remainder=MinMaxScaler())

pipe = pipe.fit(training_content)
```

But I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_clfs.py", line 336, in <module>
    pipe = pipe.fit(training_content)
  File "/root/semantic_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 494, in fit
    self.fit_transform(X, y=y)
  File "/root/semantic_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 553, in fit_transform
    return self._hstack(list(Xs))
  File "/root/semantic_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py", line 639, in _hstack
    return np.hstack(Xs)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in hstack
  File "/root/semantic_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 346, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 19872
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)